# Unable to access Spring Boot Actuator "/actuator" endpoint

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I am able to access endpoints like `http://localhost:8081/health`, `/status`, `/env`, `/metrics`, `/shutdown`  but **not** `/actuator` or `/loginfo` endpoints.

Getting below exception.

```
{"timestamp":1455929182552,"status":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"No message available","path":"/actuator"}
```

How to acccess http://localhost:8081/actuator endpoint?

Comment: Is [spring-boot-starter-actuator](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-enabling.html#production-ready-enabling) in your dependencies?

Comment: Yes i have it in my dependencies.

Comment: Was it resolved? I am also facing same issue. Spring boot version used-1.3.2

Comment: for me its weird, I am getting 404 when I run packaged jar :(

Answer (score 54):

As of spring boot version 2.0.1 using below property would work

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=<comma separated endpoints you wish to expose>
```

You can use `*` wildcard to expose all actuator endpoints over the web if security isn't your concern.

Also endpoints seems to have moved from previous versions. For ex. if you wish to use beans, you would now have `/actuator/beans` endpoint.

Just to be sure look at startup logs for such endpoints.

More on endpoints can be found [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html)

Comment: Make sure to include the dependency spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure

Comment: When using application.yml instead of application.properties I could not get * to work so I had to list out the various endpoints (available from the link).  Thanks.

    management:
      endpoints:
        web:
          exposure:
            include: beans,env,health,info

Answer (score 20):

If you type `http://localhost:8080/actuator/`  yo'll get the list of endpoints that has been exposed by default (3 endpoint) so in order to expose all your endpoint what you have to add in your `application.properties/yml` file:

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
```

Answer (score 13):

It looks like you mapped your `Actuator` endpoints to the base path `/`. Check if you have the following line in your configuration:

```
management.endpoints.web.base-path=/
```

So, if you omit this line, then you will access all endpoints under `actuator` path, e.g.:

```
http://localhost:8081/actuator/health
```

and the actuator itself will become accessible here:

```
http://localhost:8081/actuator
```

Answer (score 9):

i was facing same problem, after spending hours, could resolve.
first thing we need to set below property to *

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
management.endpoints.enabled-by-default=false
```

and we need to provide the below property port, instead on server.port in the URL.

```
management.server.port=9000
```

example:

```
http://localhost:9000/actuator/loggers/{package}
http://localhost:9000/actuator/health
```

This is tried in a micro-service with spring boot 2.1.13, with below properties and worked fine.

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
management.endpoint.loggers.enabled=true
management.endpoint.restart.enabled=true
management.endpoint.refresh.enabled=true
management.endpoint.health.enabled=true
management.security.enabled=false
management.health.db.enabled=true
management.health.diskspace.enabled=true
```

Answer (score 7):

as of `springboot 2.0.5.RELEASE`  the health check endpoint is `http://hostname:portnumber/applicationroot/actuator/health`

also check if you have added the dependency

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 5):

**Actuator endpoints moved in Spring Boot 2.0.0**, so you need to check `/application/health`.

Gradle:

```
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
springBootVersion = '2.0.0.M3'*
```

Edit the build.gradle file and change the Boot version to 1.5.4.RELEASE. Run the app.

```
curl -i localhost:8080/health

HTTP/1.1 200
X-Application-Context: application
Content-Type: application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Wed, 14 Jun 2017 20:45:51 GMT

{"status":"UP"}
```

Comment: Yeah, i can get to /application endpoint but thats the only one.  Cant get to /heath , etc .

Comment: Acutator endpoints got moved again, the prefix is now `/actuator` instead of `/application`

Answer (score 5):

I got a pretty descriptive message

```
2017-11-09 23:27:14.572  INFO 30483 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] s.b.a.e.m.MvcEndpointSecurityInterceptor : Full authentication is required to access actuator endpoints. Consider adding Spring Security or set 'management.security.enabled' to false.
```

So I put the property in the applicaiton.properties

```
management.security.enabled=false
```

And it will worked.

**UPDATE**: `management.security.enabled` is now deprecated in spring boot 2, thanks 
@Abdelghani Roussi

Comment: `management.security.enabled` is now deprecated in spring boot 2

Answer (score 4):

Base on @Vinod's answer, I add application.yml content.
For spring boot 2.1.0 please add below property value in application.yml file.

```
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: '*'
  endpoint:
    health:
      show-details: always
    beans:
      enabled: true
```

Access below url from your local system[either browser or postman] from where you are running a application.

```
http://localhost:8080/actuator/metrics
http://localhost:8080/actuator/health
http://localhost:8080/actuator/beans
```

More endpoint, see the link:
[Part V. Spring Boot Actuator: Production-ready features](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html)

Answer (score 4):

I had display issue with http://localhost:8080/actuator/ and got resolved by adding hal-explorer dependency. Please make sure to have below 2 dependencies in your pom.xml to display correct content for actuator.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-rest-hal-explorer</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Also check below properties in your application.properties

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
#management.endpoints.enabled-by-default=false
#management.endpoints.web.base-path=/
```

Comment: I tried everything until found your message but no one add this dependency on the pom file to see actuator results. Interesting...

Answer (score 3):

check https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide#base-path

change the application.properties fle for this would allow you use 
http://localhost:8080/beans (or /health , /env )

```
server.port=8080
management.endpoints.web.base-path=/
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
```

Answer (score 3):

```
For spring boot 2.x.x please add below property value in application.property file.

management.endpoint.health.show-details=ALWAYS
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
management.endpoint.beans.enabled=true

Access below url from your local system[either browser or postman] from where you are running a application.

http://localhost:8080/actuator/metrics
http://localhost:8080/actuator/health
http://localhost:8080/actuator/beans
```

Answer (score 3):

health check endpoint as of Spring Boot **2.1.5.RELEASE**

http://localhost:8080/actuator/health

check if you have added the dependency

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
 </dependency>
```

check if you have added the **application.properties**

management.endpoints.web.exposure.include     = *

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that those 'sensitive' endpoints are enabled. [This doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html) describes how to enable all sensitive endpoints or individual ones. It sounds like you have certain sensitive endpoints enabled (like shutdown) but not others (like actuator).

To enable all sensitive endpoints:

```
endpoints.sensitive=true
```

To enable actuator and logfile individually:

```
endpoints.actuator.enabled=true
endpoints.logfile.enabled=true
```

Comment: I already have them in my properties file `endpoints.beans.id=springbeans
endpoints.beans.sensitive=true
endpoints.shutdown.enabled=true
endpoints.enabled=true
endpoints.info.enabled=true
endpoints.metrics.id=metrics
endpoints.metrics.sensitive=true
endpoints.metrics.enabled=true
endpoints.actuator.enabled=true
endpoints.logfile.enabled=true

management.port=8081
management.security.enabled=true
management.security.role=SUPERUSER

security.user.name=admin
security.user.password=secret123
security.require_ssl=false
security.basic.enabled=true`

Comment: This is the example i am trying to work on [link](https://github.com/bkielczewski/example-spring-boot-actuator)

Answer (score 2):

First you should make sure you have the following dependencies in your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Then you should have the following configuration in your application.yml

```
 management:
      endpoint:
        health:
          enabled: true
          show-details: always
      endpoints:
        web:
          exposure:
            include: '*'
        jmx:
          exposure:
            include: '*'
```

You can customize the information in the info enpoit with the following configuration inside the application.yml

```
info:
    app:
        name: @project.name@
        description: @project.description@
        version: @project.version@
        encoding: @project.build.sourceEncoding@
        java:
            version: @java.version@
```

After That, you can go to the url **localhost:8080** and see the list of endpoints as follows:

[image]

Hope this answer can help someone

Comment: thanks, for me the only way to make it work was to add also the 
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>. Found nowhere else this info :)

Answer (score 1):

spring boot `1.5.6`

> actuator
>   Provides a hypermedia-based “discovery page” for the other endpoints. Requires Spring HATEOAS to be on the classpath.

please see: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.6.RELEASE/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html

Answer (score 1):

I always prefer to provide context path with the base URL of application. Now to configure actuator we should include below dependency into our pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

let it use the default version which is being beared by Spring boot version.
Put below properties into your application.properties

```
server.servlet.contextPath=/<app-name>
server.port=8080

management.endpoint.metrics.enabled=true
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
management.endpoint.prometheus.enabled=true
management.metrics.export.prometheus.enabled=true
management.security.enabled=false
management.health.mongo.enabled=false
management.health.redis.enabled=false
management.health.rabbit.enabled=false
management.endpoint.health.show-details=always

#/metrics endpoint configuration
endpoints.metrics.id=metrics
endpoints.metrics.sensitive=false
endpoints.metrics.enabled=true

#/health endpoint configuration (Comment when you are using customized health check)
endpoints.health.id=health
endpoints.health.sensitive=false
endpoints.health.enabled=true

info.app.name=@project.name@
info.app.description=@project.description@
info.app.version=@project.version@
info.app.encoding=@project.build.sourceEncoding@
info.app.java.version=@java.version@
```

After above configuration once you start your server , you can easily check the metrics as below http calls-

```
 # curl http://localhost:8080/myapp/actuator/metrics
 {
  "names": ["jvm.buffer.memory.used", "jvm.gc.memory.allocated", 
  "jvm.memory.committed", "jvm.memory.used", "http.server.requests", 
  "jvm.gc.max.data.size", "logback.events", "system.cpu.count", 
  "jvm.memory.max", "jvm.buffer.total.capacity", "jvm.buffer.count", 
  "process.files.max", "jvm.threads.daemon", "process.start.time", 
  "jvm.gc.live.data.size", "process.files.open", "process.cpu.usage", 
  "process.uptime", "system.load.average.1m", "jvm.gc.pause", 
  "system.cpu.usage", "jvm.threads.live", "jvm.classes.loaded", 
  "jvm.classes.unloaded", "jvm.threads.peak", "jvm.gc.memory.promoted"]
}
```

For details you can watch my blog [here](https://www.javatechnologylovers.com/2019/07/spring-boot-actuators.html)

Answer (score 1):

For those, who do not use anything in the Spring Boot like I do (I use Spring Integration IP and listen for packets): **you still need the following dependency** for `/actuator` to work (regardless of if it'll be running on the `server.port` or `management.server.port`):

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Without this dependency, the actuator will not appear in the startup log **at all**.

You do not need to use Spring Security though unless you want to secure endpoints.

Sergio Sánchez Sánchez pointed this out in an answer above, but in my opinion it was not clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

1. Check in your console for errors like "invalid LOC header (bad signature)".
   Do 'mvn spring-boot:run' to get logs.
   My sprint-boot-starter-actuator was corrupted !
2. In my case the actuators url are

   - http://localhost:8080/actuators/metrics
   - http://localhost:8080/actuators/autoconfig
   - etc.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is no endpoint named /loginfo according to the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html)

for /actuator endpoint, please see [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45290254/1085722) on the similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45289481/accessing-localhost8080-actuator-endpoint-with-spring-boot-actuator)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the `application.yml` file to change base path to / & disable /info.

```
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      base-path: /
  endpoint:
    #Disable /info
    info:
      enabled: false
    health:
      show-details: always
  health:
      defaults:
        enabled: false
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the `base-path` config like this

```
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      base-path: /actuator
      exposure:
        include: info, health
```