# Accessing localhost:8080/actuator endpoint (with spring boot actuator)

Tags: spring-boot, endpoint, spring-boot-actuator

In spring [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html) I have read about endpoint named "actuator" which is provided by actuator dependency, but I haven't managed to access it on my local testing app.

**Question:** Does someone know how to access that endpoint? of coarse if it is possible :)
**Sub-question 1:** If this endpoint exists, then why it is hidden?
**Sub-question 2:** If this endpoint doesn't exist, how can we notify spring.io to correct documentation page (open some kind of ticket) ?

**Details:**

- I want to access exactly "actuator" endpoint, not other endpoints provided by spring boot actuator (localhost:8080/actuator)
- Yes, I have tried to enable that endpoint manually in properties file (endpoints.enabled=true OR endpoints.actuator.enabled=true)
- Yes, I have tried to enable/disable endpoints.sencitive property
- Yes, other endpoints of actuator work just fine
- No special reason why I need that, just want to try it out (just learning new stuff :) )
- Please don't just answer "there is no such endpoint dude!", there should be some kind of reason why it is written in the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html)
- Please use spring boot version which I am using now before answering "it is working for me with these configs" (**spring boot version: 1.5.4.RELEASE**)
- Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Did you try hitting the management endpoint? 
management.server.port=8081
see: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-monitoring.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must include the **[Spring Hateoas](https://projects.spring.io/spring-hateoas/)** dependency in order for the `/actuator` endpoint to become available:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.hateoas</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-hateoas</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Per the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html):

> Provides a hypermedia-based “discovery page” for the other endpoints.
>   Requires Spring HATEOAS to be on the classpath.