# Why in my case Spring Boot Actuator does not show /info, /actuator endpoints?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-starter

Every time I get 404 error while asking for `localhost:60001/info`, `localhost:60001/actuator` or others.

```
{"timestamp":1570711643410,"status":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"No message available","path":"/loginfo"}
```

It works only for `localhost:60001/metrics` and `localhost:60001/health`.

In my application.yml file, I added all settings to enable all possible endpoints.

```
management:
  server:
    port: 60001
  security:
    enabled: false
  endpoint:
    beans:
      enabled: true
    health:
      show-details: ALWAYS
  endpoints:
    sensitive: true
    web:
      exposure:
        include: *
```

PS: I am also questioned about, why JAR file builds successfully even if I will write management settings in application.yml with mistakes. For example, `show-details: SOME_NOT_EXISTING_THING` instead of `show-details: ALWAYS`

I also added `SecurityWebFilterChain` bean which I saw in [Baeldung tutorial for Spring Boot 2.x Actuator](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-actuators#boot-2x-actuator)

```
@Bean
public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(
  ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    return http.authorizeExchange()
      .pathMatchers("/actuator/**").permitAll()
      .anyExchange().authenticated()
      .and().build();
}
```

I tried all possible `localhost:60001/` links which have been written in this [stackoverflow issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35517713/unable-to-access-spring-boot-actuator-actuator-endpoint).

PS: `http://hostname:portnumber/applicationroot/actuator/health`, `http://localhost:60001/loginfo` and others. But it still doesn't work.

I use Spring Boot 2.1.6:RELEASE

Comment: which spring boot version are you using?

Comment: @Shailesh I use Spring Boot 2.1.6:RELEASE

Answer (score 0):

**Couldn't post in comments**

can you try below yml, as Star(*) without double quotes was not valid in my IDE, might be your problem is same

```
management:
  endpoints:
    enabled-by-default: true
    web:
      exposure:
        include:
        - "*"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Ok, I changed it to double-quotes. But still, nothing has been changed.

Comment: try my sample actuator project https://github.com/KoolShailesh/so-problems/tree/master/sample-actuator-project